# In JavaScript, How to extract latitude and longitude from string

Tags: javascript, regex, latitude-longitude, string-parsing

I am extracting a string from a database which needs to be parsed into latitude and longitude separately, 
The string is defined as a "point", in the following format:

`(2.340000000,-4.50000000)`

I am trying to remove the parenthesis, and then parsed them with the method `split()` but I haven't been able to come up with a regular expressions that does the job right:

So far I have tried many alternatives, and

```
var latlong = "(2.34000000, -4.500000000)"
latlong.replace('/[\(\)]//g','');
var coords = latlong.split(',');
var lat = coords[0];
var long = coords[1];
```

If I run that, all I got is:
`NaN, -4.500000`

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: I ran your code and it works. You havo problems somewhere else.

Comment: Ive tried running this in jsfiddle and it prints the correct long and lat. Try alert(long + " " + lat)

Comment: your code is right you just need to store the return value from replacement .... see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/cYrh5/1/), but you had an extra slash

```
var value = '(2.340000000,-4.50000000)';

//you had an extra slash here
//           ''''''''''''''''v
value = value.replace(/[\(\)]/g,'').split(',');

console.log(value[0]);
console.log(value[1]);​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cut out the split and just use the match function with the regex `\((\-?\d+\.\d+), (\-?\d+\.\d+)\)` which will return the two coordinates. Firebug console output:

```
>>> "(2.34000000, -4.500000000)".match(/\((\-?\d+\.\d+), (\-?\d+\.\d+)\)/);
["(2.34000000, -4.500000000)", "2.34000000", "-4.500000000"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) function:

```
var latlong = "(2.34000000, -4.500000000)"
var coords = latlong.match(/\((-?[0-9\.]+), (-?[0-9\.]+)\)/);

var lat = coords[1];
var long = coords[2];
alert('lat: ' + lat);
alert('long: ' + long);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var latlong = "(2.34000000, -4.500000000)"
 var coords = latlong.replace(/[\(\) ]/g,'').split(',');

 console.log(coords[0])
 console.log(coords[1])
```