# Extract Latitude and Longitude by Javascript from String

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

How do i extract Latitude and Longitude from the below url using Javascript/Regex .

https://www.google.co.in/maps/search/wipro+Technologies/@**12.974267**,**80.2238546**,13z/data=!3m1!4b1?hl=en

I want 12.974267 assigned to a variable and 80.2238546 to longitude variable

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [In JavaScript, How to extract latitude and longitude from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530279/in-javascript-how-to-extract-latitude-and-longitude-from-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Without Regex:** [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zbspxLxp/)

```
var url = 'https://www.google.co.in/maps/search/wipro+Technologies/@12.974267,80.2238546,13z/data=!3m1!4b1?hl=en';

var splitUrl = url.split('@');
var coords = splitUrl[1].split(',');

console.log(coords[0]); // 12.974267
console.log(coords[1]); // 80.2238546
```

**Regex:** `/@\d+\.\d+,\d+\.\d+/`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, simple jquery solution to extract the values you need

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var v = "https://www.google.co.in/maps/search/wipro+Technologies/@12.974267,80.2238546,13z/data=!3m1!4b1?hl=en";

  var a = v.split(',');
  alert("latitude:" + a[0].split('@')[1])
  alert("longitude:" + a[1]);




})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```